# How to read from .txt file and seperate each line into different strings and store them into different struct variables?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct record
{
     char id[10];
     char firstName[20];
     char lastName[20];
     char score[5];
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fileptr;
    fileptr=fopen("students.txt","r");

    struct record *pinakas;

    pinakas=(struct record *)malloc(17*sizeof(struct record));

    fflush(stdin);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        fgets(pinakas+i,70,fileptr);
    }

    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        puts(pinakas+i);
    }

    fclose(fileptr);
    free(pinakas);

    return 0;
}
```

and let's say i have the following .txt file :

### RT56996 George Clark 9.0

### RT68494 Emilia Anderson 6.0

### . . .

### RT5858 Helen White 10.0

What i do here as you see is that i read the file and store each line into struct object "pinakas" . The problem is that i don't know how to divide each (pinakas+i) by space and store every string into id,firstName, lastName, score ... Any idea ?

Comment: You can read into a temporary buffer instead of directly into the target structs, and use string.h methods to split each line to 4 parts. Then, copy each part to the right field in the struct.

Comment: Can you tell me how to split each line into four parts and store each string into the struct variables ?

Comment: [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (to read the line into a *string* buffer) and [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)?

Comment: Thank you for answering me with a question :)

Comment: Oh and calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like e.g. `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as being *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use fscanf as the code below, it is a function use to scan on files.
"%[^ ]" means scanning everything until ' ' is found.
"%[^\n]" means scanning everything until '\n' is found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct record{
 char id[10];
 char firstName[20];
 char lastName[20];
 char score[5];
};

int main(){
FILE *fileptr;

int i=0,idx=0;

fileptr=fopen("students.txt","r");
struct record *pinakas;
pinakas=(struct record *)malloc(17*sizeof(struct record));

if(fileptr){
    while(!feof(fileptr)){
        fscanf(fileptr,"%[^ ] %[^ ] %[^ ] %[^\n]\n",pinakas[idx].id,pinakas[idx].firstName,pinakas[idx].lastName,pinakas[idx].score);
        idx++;
    }
}

int i=0;

for(i=0; i<idx; i++){
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n",pinakas[i].id,pinakas[i].firstName,pinakas[i].lastName,pinakas[i].score);
}

fclose(fileptr);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard ! Your answer helped a lot